# C# : шифрование ПИН-блока в ISO8583

Tags: c#, стандарт, iso

**Добрый день.**

Сейчас пишу реализацию протокола ISO8553, а конкретнее - установка / смена PIN'а карты.  Поле 52 - зашифрованный ПИН-блок, где на основании ПИНа формируется ПИН-блок, затем он шифруется.

Для полноты картину приведу описание этого поля из стандарта:

> ENCRYPTED PIN BLOCK. For more comfortable viewing hence and further
>   PERSONAL IDENTIFICATION DATA is presented as 16 HEXADECIMAL characters
>   0-9, A-F in the ASCII with separator ‘.’ between each two characters

Пример заполненного поля:

> 34.56.F4.3B.6E.D2.77.8B

**Теперь вопрос:**

В описании написано, что пин-блок (а это **16**(!) символов переводится в HEX, с разделителем точкой) Приведенный мною выше пример заполнения поля в HEX-эдиторе не расшифровывается вообще.

Пример моего ПИН-блока: (тут ПИН = 1234, формат 1)

> 1412345478541264

Так я перевожу строку ПИН-блока в HEX:

```
 foreach (char t in PIN_block_encr)
                sb.Append(Convert.ToInt32(t).ToString("x") + ".");
```

**Мне кажется, я где-то ошибаюсь или чего-то недопонимаю :(**

**Как правильно перевести в моем случае 16 символов ПИН-блока (тип string) в HEX?**

Спасибо.

Comment: Будет полезным? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/377446/BIM-ISO

Comment: нет, эта тема с статье опускается. Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря что вам надо получить.

Если вы хотите перевести побайтно, и вывести все байты разделив их точкой, то вам для начала нужно разделить число на байты. Как это делать, зависит от точного типа. Например, может подойти

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
```

(Заметьте, что `number` должен быть числом, а не строкой. Если это строка, надо предварительно перевести его в число подходящего типа.)

Затем можно закодировать каждый байт:

```
string.Join(".", bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X"));
```

---

Если вам нужно перевести всё число в «большую» шестнадцатеричную строку, делайте как написано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416733/10105).

---

Если вам, наоборот, надо считать число из вашей записи, делаем так:

Разбиваем строку на части:

```
var parts = s.Split('.');
```

Каждую часть раскодируем:

```
var bytes = parts.Select(p => byte.Parse(p, NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

И склеиваем в число. Поскольку у вас 8 байт, подойдёт `ulong`:

```
var result = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes.ToArray(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Написано же: **ENCRYPTED PIN BLOCK**. Как вы вообще хотели посмотреть его в шестнадцатиричном редакторе без предварительной расшифровки?

Comment: ENCRYPTED в данном случае означает простой перевод строки пин-блока в HEX.