# C#: из десятичной в шестнадцатеричную С.И

Tags: c#, системы-счисления

**Добрый день!**

Имеется строка чисел: 1400001111111111 (всего 16 символов) - десятичная система.
Пытаюсь в конвертировать в шестнадцатеричную:

```
    //variant 1
    return string.Join(".", PIN_block_encr.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X2")));
    //variant 2
    var a = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PIN_block_encr);
    var c = BitConverter.ToString(a);
```

(пример кода)
Результат всех способов что я опробовал аналогичен - "

> 31.34.30.30.30.30.31.31.31.31.31.31.31.31.31.31

"
Я решил проверить с помощью с помощью онлайн-переводчика (10=>16) [этот, например](http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/RU/units-converter/numbers/4-3/), и он мне выдал в моем случае совсем другое :

> 4F94B28E9B5C7

Разница очевидна. Причем я больше склоняюсь ко 2-ому варианту.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно его реализовать на c#. Спасибо.**

Comment: Ответ уже есть. Здесь еще куча его вариаций http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again

Comment: @PleshkovIvan: Но вопросы на русском гугл будет направлять сюда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала, получите число:

```
var n = long.Parse("1400001111111111");
```

За тем выводите:

```
var hexstr = n.ToString("X");
```

`long` вместо `int` нужен потому, что ваше число в `int` не помещается.

[Результат](http://ideone.com/9znLlB): 4F94B28E9B5C7.

Comment: Лидирующие нули теряются же.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А они нужны? Если да, то `X16` покатит: http://ideone.com/IKTC3f

Comment: + @Memoizer, в вопросе же говорится про перевод. Да и в коде в вопросе приведено X2.

Answer (score 3):

```
    UInt64 val = 1400001111111111;
    Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("X"));  // C  ~ possibly single-digit output 
    Console.WriteLine(val.ToString("X2")); // 0C ~ allways double-digit output
```

Answer (score 1):

Если известно, что строка состоит из чисел, но количество их неизвестно, то имеет смысл воспользоваться классом BigInteger (ему можно скормить любую строку чисел, в разумных пределах, конечно).

```
var bi = BigInteger.Parse("1400001111111111");
var result = bi.ToString("x");
```

Comment: Тоже лидирующие нули...

Comment: @Qwertiy если они нужны, то использовать ToString("x16"). Но автор вопроса привел пример желаемого результата, он без нулей.